# Replacing strings with values from dictionary using random.sample

Tags: python, dictionary, random

Suppose I'm creating a madLib and i want to replace each word from a string that has the word `'plural noun'`. Basically, the user gets a prompt that states to input plural nouns and those inputs the go to a dictionary (`pluralnoDict`).

I've been using `random.choice`, and it's been working out, however, the repeats is obviously the issue. I tried `random.sample`, however, instead of choosing one word from a given sample, the code replaces the words with the whole sample.

Is there a way I can replace each string using `random.sample` from a dictionary list? For example:

Original: The `'plural noun'` have `'plural noun'` and `'plural noun'`.
Expected: The `'birds'` have `'wings'` and `'feet'`.

Below is the for loop i use to replace the plural noun strings.

```
for key in pluralnoDict:
        target_word = "({0})".format(key)
        while target_word in madString:
            madString = madString.replace(target_word, random.choice(pluralnoDict[key]), 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use all of the nouns, but in a random order, you could use `random.shuffle` and do something like:

```py
from random import shuffle

target_word = "plural noun"
mad_str = "The 'plural noun' have 'plural noun' and 'plural noun'"
plural_nouns = ["birds", "feet", "wings"]
shuffle(plural_nouns)
for noun in plural_nouns:
    mad_str = mad_str.replace(target_word, noun, 1)
print(mad_str)
```

Comment: This is it right here. Appreciate it! I was specifically looking for the string replacement to come from a set of dictionary values, but coming from a list works too!

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into the `random` library? You can use it to get random indices and so, to the best of my understanding, a possible solution could look something like this:

```py
import re
import random

list_of_words = ["dogs", "cats", "mice"]

mad_lib = "the quick brown plural noun jumped over the lazy plural noun"

while "plural noun" in mad_lib:
    random_index = random.randint(0, len(list_of_words))
    mad_lib = re.sub("plural noun", list_of_words[random_index], mad_lib, 1)
    del list_of_words[random_index]

print(mad_lib)
```